# Why can't Intel CPU use AMD chipsets and vice versa?

Tags: networking, cpu, motherboard, pci-express

In my own intrepretation, a [chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chipset) is just a hardware that implements PCIE, which is basically the communication protocol used by the CPU to communicate with [device controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_adapter).

Now, PCIE is an open protocol / non-proprietary protocol, just like IP, Ethernet, USB, etc. If we have for example a Cisco Ethernet switch, we know that a Mac computer, a Windows PC, and a Linux PC can connect to it because they all support Ethernet.

So if AMD creates a hardware that implements PCIE, why can't Intel use it? And if Intel creates a hardware that implements PCIE, why can't AMD use it?

Comment: “In my own intrepretation, a chipset is just a hardware that implements PCIE”—that’s not how it is though.

Comment: Intel only licenses x86 to AMD and AMD only licenses x64 to Intel otherwise Intel and AMD are competitors. AMD is required to license x64 back to Intel.